# How to move JavaScript string containing HTML code to it's own file

Tags: javascript, html, django

In HTML, you can write JavaScript code in the HTML file using the script 
tag, and later extract that script to it's own file.  I need to do the opposite.  I have a JavaScript file containing HTML code stored as a string variable.

For example:

```
var foo = '<p>lots of code here</p>'
```

How can I extract the HTML code to its own file and link it back to its original position in the JavaScript file?

The section of code that I am working on is a collapsible element of another HTML document that is part of a Django view.

Comment: can you give an example? If you have the variable in Javascript file, then you can use that variable where ever as long as you import the js file?

Answer (score 0):

---

You can add your html code is a new django template or static file

e.g. template.tplt

```
<script type="template" id="my_template">
    <p>lots of code here</p>
</script>
```

and then load that static file in which ever page that requires it and in your js you can do

```
var foo = $('#my_template').html()
```

you can also not load the static file in the template and just request it via ajax.

you can also use a js templating library like https://github.com/janl/mustache.js/ to make your life easier :)

Comment: I have a couple questions.  First, how do I load the static file?  I've only been able to find methods of loading static stylesheets and the staticfiles documentation from django.  Second, is linking the extracted html code to the javascript file the same as above if the files are in different directories?  I'm still really new to django so any help is appreciated.